# ORA-00923: palabra clave FROM no encontrada donde se esperaba - Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, sqlplus

**Hola buenas noches, estaba escribiendo este código en el comando de Oracle (sql plus) y me sale error en linea 2**

Codigo:

```
SQL> SELECT tablespace_name,
  2  SUM <mbtotal> / 1024 / 1024 mbtotal,
  3  SUM < mbtotal - mblibre> / 1024 / 1024 mbusado,
  4  SUM <mblibre> / 1024 / 1024 mblibre,
  5  round<<<SUM < mbtotal - mblibre> / 1024 / 1024> * 100> / <SUM <mbtotal> / 1024 / 1024>, 2> Porc_ocu,
  6  round<<<SUM <mblibre> / 1024 / 1024> *100> / <SUM <mbtotal> / 1024 / 1024>, 2> Porc_libre
  7  FROM <SELECT tablespace_name, bytes mbtotal, 0 mblibre
  8  FROM dba_data_files
  9  UNION ALL
 10  SELECT tablespace_name, 0 mbtotal, bytes mblibre
 11  FROM dba_free_space>
 12  GROUP BY tablespace_name
 13  order by 6
 14  /
SUM <mbtotal> / 1024 / 1024 mbtotal,
    *
ERROR en lÝnea 2:
ORA-00923: palabra clave FROM no encontrada donde se esperaba
```

Si alguien me puede ayudar se los agradezco mucho

Aclaro que tengo instalado oracle 18c express edition

Comment: ¿Qué es lo quieres conseguir? Lo pregunto porque no comprendo la línea `FROM <SELECT tablespace_name, bytes mbtotal, 0 mblibre`. Saludos.

Comment: Quiero que me muestre el tamaño que le puse a mis tablespace cuando los cree

Comment: Entiendo, en la línea 7 y 8 entiendo que estás intentando una subconsulta, entonces tendrías que encerrar la subconsulta entre <> y ponerle un alias, intenta esto en las líneas 7 y 8: `FROM <SELECT tablespace_name, bytes mbtotal, 0 mblibre FROM dba_data_files> x`

Comment: Ya sustituí esa nueva linea de codigo por las lineas 7 y 8 y me sigue dando el mismo error

Comment: Josue Arriola, ya me salió hice lo que me dijiste, sobre no poner<> y era ()